# Upgrade back to latest Nautilus/Files after downgrading

Tags: 13.10, nautilus

I made a mistake of installing or downgrading nautilus. I am using Ubuntu 13.10 32-bit. On the Launcher, when I right-click at the File, there are options for Documents, Downloads, Music, etc, making it a bit easier to open the desired location. How do I go about installing the nautilus version that originally came with the OS? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

try the following command,

```
sudo apt-get install nautilus
```

it will ask for your password; enter it then nautilus should be updated. but watch the console because it might ask you if you want to use that much space on your hard drive. if it does type y for yes or n for no.

Comment: Press ctrl + alt + T to open terminal; i did not specify where to type this sorry.

Comment: Thank you for putting that in the paste box @Avinash Raj